# date field do not want to display

Tags: php, html, date

`$customers_dob` is valid : `string(10) "06/11/2019"` but when I insert the code below : `$customers_dob` is displayed empty.

my code is :

```
echo HTML::inputField('dob', $customers_dob, null, 'date');
```

I tested with a full HTMl code:

```
echo '<input id="date" type="date" value="' . $customers_dob . '">';
```

I have the same result `$customers_dob` : is displayed empty.

Do you have an idea to display the value inside the input date?

Comment: What is `06/11/2019`? You need to learn to use dates in ISO-8601 format and only display in local format when needed for users.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Also can you show us the code that is setting this variable's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML5 accepts date values in ISO-8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value). The format you are using can be ambiguous.

You can convert the date to `Y-m-d` using PHP and display that into HTML

```
$dateObj = new \DateTime('06/11/2019');
echo '<input id="date" type="date" value="' . $dateObj->format('Y-m-d') . '">';
```